# Copy taxonomy term name to another field

Tags: entities

I need coordinates for each term in a cities taxonomy I got one a site for one of my clients. I found Geofield, which I use on nodes on that very same site, and it works as it should. However in my city taxonomy Geofield has a bug that makes it unable to get coordinates based on a title, which the term name is.

So I figured that I might copy the value of the title into another field for a term - like Title Copy field, and then base Geofield coordinates by that. Now, I don't know how..

I've found Computed Field which I find to complex for this, Tokens I don't get to work, Reference auto fill needs yet another source field so it goes away.

Any ideas for a simple solution that will work with terms created from both the taxonomy UI AND when nodes add new terms from a Autocomplete field?

Comment: Could https://drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel help you?

Comment: Thank you, Pontus. Unfortunately not though.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a content type with a field 
"Title" of type "Term Reference"... and you want to pass an address from this existing field to a hidden field for Geo coding or whatever else for that specific page.

I would suggest using views and [entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) to do this. This method is useful for passing multiple fields, but can be used to grab just one...

Once you have the Entity Reference module enabled and installed create a view. For the view's display options (that + sign) add 'Entity Reference'.

Add a field to this view of type: "Content: All taxonomy terms"

In the next options screen you can limit the options here to your specific 'Cities' vocabulary.

You now need to add a contextual filter 'Content:NID' to get this view to only display the city term reference for the page that it's on.

Now go back to your content type and add a field of type 'Entity Reference'. Configure it like this:

- Target Type - Node
- Mode - Views (filter by an entity reference view)
- View used to select the entities - 'my entity reference view'

Now add your Geofield and configure it to 'Geocode from another field' - i.e. your entity reference field (which you can hide in the display options)

In the event that a city name alone is insufficient to geocode from consider adding other fields to your content type and passing them to your entity reference view.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. The coordinates has to be stored with the taxonomy term, not a node. But thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to use Rules.

1. Create a text field to be used for the copied value from name/title
   of the term (aka "copy field" for now).
2. Create a geofield that bases the coordinates from the copy field.
3. Create a rule that will be run before a taxonomy term is saved.
4. Set an action that copies the value of name/title field to your copy field.
5. Create a action to run some PHP code and add: taxonomy_term_save($term);
6. Save the rule.
7. Save a taxonomy and it will copy the name/title to the copy field and get the coordinates from that field.